# Does this identity involving limits hold?

Tags: calculus, limits

If two sequences converge equally, we have 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left ( a_{n} \right )=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left ( b_{n} \right )$$

As a follow up, is the following equality also true?
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left ( \ln a_{n} \right )=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left ( \ln b_{n} \right )$$

Notice that I didn't put absolute value brackets, because I am working with sequences involving only positive terms at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } b_{n} >0$ then you can use that $\ln$ is a continuous function. And, if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } b_{n} =0$ then you have that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\ln a_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \ln b_{n} =-\infty.$

Comment: Good point there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because $\mathrm{ln}$ is continuous.

(Of course, the question only makes sense if $a_n>0$ and $b_n>0$ for (almost) all $n$.)

Comment: Yeah, of course, because even if there were a small amount of negative terms, they still wouldn't play a role in the convergence of a sequence.